# Exporting multiple functions with arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

All I am trying to do is to export two functions from a module. One function taking an argument and the other with no argument:

```
function initClass(params)
{
   return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        if (!wallet) {
            wallet = new WalletClient(params);
            resolve(wallet);
        } else {
            console.log('Wallet is initialized');
            resolve(wallet);
        }
});
}

function getInstance()
{
   return wallet;
}
```

For `initClass(params)` only, I can do this as:

```
module.exports = (params) => {
   initClass(params)
}
```

And then I call this as:

```
var init = require('./class.js')(params).initClass(params);
```

This works fine.

Now, for me to export `getInstance()` as well, I have tried to do the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
module.exports = (params) => {
   initClass(params),
   getInstance
}
```

This complaints that there is no function `getInstance`.

Then I tried this:

```
module.exports.init = (params) => {
   initClass(params)
}

module.exports.instance = {
   getInstance
}
```

Then call them as:

```
var init = require('./class.js').init(params).initClass(params);
```

What is the proper way to export multiple functions like this?
Thank you.

Comment: Regardless of `import/export`, to call `initClass` chained to `init`, `init` would have to return something that has `initClass` on its prototype - which it clearly doesn't

Comment: Your *`var init = require('./class.js')(params).initClass(params);`* call does not look valid. Or are you returning something from the exported function?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I am exporting an instantiated class from `initClass`

Comment: @madu Then please show the actual code.

Comment: @Bergi added the code of `initClass`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making it more complex than needed.  Once you have your functions defined, you can export it with this:

```
module.exports = {
  initClass,
  getInstance
}
```

To use it, you do this:

```
const init = require("./class.js");
init.initClass(params);
const instance = init.getInstance();
```

What you're exporting from the module is an object (which I've named `init` in the example above) that contains two functions. You don't have to pass arguments to the functions at the time you `require`.

Answer (score 2):

module.exports is basically an object with keys which can refer to any variables/functions of your file.In your case,

```
module.exports.initClass = function (params){
...
}

module.exports.getInstance = function (){
}
```

When importing it

```
var init = require('./class.') // init object has two keys -> initClass and getInstance
 init.initClass('abc')
 init.getInstance()
```

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding correctly you are trying to export multiple methods if that is the case simple use this.

```
   module.exports = {
        method: function() {},
        otherMethod: function(parmas) {}
    }
```

In your code use like this.

```
 var init = require('./class.js');
    init.method()
    init.otherMethond(paramObj)
```

If you want below scenario you need to check out about method chaining.

```
var init = require('./class.js').init(params).initClass(params);
```

Comment: Thank you Venkat. I tried doing `require('./class.js').init(params).initClass(params)` but it gives an error that `cant read property of undefined initClass`